# Raspberry Pi: No X11 DISPLAY variable was set, but this program performed an operation which requires it

Tags: bash, raspberry-pi

I'm using PuTTY to have the socket connection with Raspberry Pi.
I'm developing a TV scoreboard application.
I'm using WinSCP to copy those `.sh` file into the Raspberry Pi.

While I'm running a script `./timer.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

java -jar /home/pi/ScoreBoard_app/Timer/Timer.jar
```

It shows an error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.awt.HeadlessException:
No X11 DISPLAY variable was set, but this program performed an operation which requires     it.
        at java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.checkHeadless(GraphicsEnvironment.java:207)
        at java.awt.Window.<init>(Window.java:535)
        at java.awt.Frame.<init>(Frame.java:420)
        at javax.swing.JFrame.<init>(JFrame.java:224)
        at com.javafx.main.Main$1.run(Main.java:816)
        at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:251)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:733)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:694)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:692)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:703)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
```

I have even tried to set the `DISPLAY=localhost:0.0`.
It will show error that X11 server cannot connect on "localhost:10.0".

I also tried `localhost:1.0`, but I get the same error that it can't connect on "localhost:1.0".

Comment: try it, 
    xhost: unable to open display ""

Answer (score 2):

your rasperry-pi needs to enable X forwarding in `sshd_config`

you need to have a X server running on your pc, Xming is a good open source X server

after installing and starting Xming, you need to configure putty, set x display location as `localhost:0.0`

for details, search `xming putty rasperry pi`

Comment: i try it before, but i can't run it..it keep ask me to install the latest java runtime..i have installed the jdk-7u25

Comment: Run `java -version` to see whether you are using the latest java. After setting up Xming and connecting rasperry pi with putty, run `xclock`. If you can see a clock, X windows is working fine.