# java swing GUI on kura

Tags: java, swing, x11, display, kura

I need help to create a bundle in Kura that show a Swing's GUI. I'm using Java and OSGI to create bundles. I run it on raspberryPI.

I put this code inside the bundle's activator:

```
public void activate(ComponentContext componentContext, Map<String,Object> properties)
{
    System.out.println("Sono AstroGUI!!!!");

    Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
          public void run() {
        createAndShow();
          }
        };
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(runnable);
}

 static void createAndShow() {


    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Hello World");
    frame.setSize(640,480);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);
  }
```

But when I upload the bundle, the system return this error:

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.awt.HeadlessException:  No
>   X11 DISPLAY variable was set, but this program performed an operation
>   which requires it.    at
>   java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.checkHeadless(GraphicsEnvironment.java:207)
>     at java.awt.Window.(Window.java:536)  at
>   java.awt.Frame.(Frame.java:420)     at
>   javax.swing.JFrame.(JFrame.java:225)    at
>   com.riccardofontanini.astrogui.AstroGUIActivator.createAndShow(AstroGUIActivator.java:56)
>     at
>   com.riccardofontanini.astrogui.AstroGUIActivator$1.run(AstroGUIActivator.java:47)
>     at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
>     at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:744)   at
>   java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(EventQueue.java:97)    at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:697)    at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:691)    at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
>     at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:714)   at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)

Please help me!

Comment: [Maybe this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20648809/raspberry-pi-no-x11-display-variable-was-set-but-this-program-performed-an-ope) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5218870/getting-a-headlessexception-no-x11-display-variable-was-set)

Comment: or check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/5218891/4606266

Answer (score 3):

Certainly make sure X11 is setup properly as previously suggested. You can also try to edit the start up script for Kura to ensure X is ready when Kura starts. The start up scripts are located in /opt/eclipse/kura/bin. The default script that Kura uses on boot is start_kura_background.sh. Edit this file and add the following lines:

```
if ! xset q &>/dev/null; then
    echo “Starting X Server...”
    su -s /bin/bash -c xinit root& export DISPLAY=:0
    echo “X Server started !”
else
    echo “X Server already running, DISPLAY variable setted”
```

Also, what version of Java are you using? I have only seen this work on a full Oracle JRE. I have not tried Eclipse Kura + Swing on OpenJDK, and it will not work on Java Embedded.

Thanks,

--Dave

Comment: Hi, 
(I'm using eurotech's esf)
I put 

DISPLAY=localhost:0.0 

in /opt/eurotech/esf/bin/start_kura_debug_background.sh and this solve the DISPLAY problem, but now there is another one:
 
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class sun.awt.X11.XToolkit

I think this is a Java problem... or I must pack somethink in my bundle...